# How do I use modulus operator in Reason React?

Tags: reason, reason-react, rescript

When using the % operator in reason react I am left with an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1rBh.png) "The value % can't be found". Is there another word for % used in Reason react?

```ml
Js.log(20 % 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reason syntax for modulus is "mod".

```ml
Js.log(20 mod 2)
```

Comment: Documented here: https://reasonml.github.io/api/Pervasives.html#VAL(mod). The parentheses means it's an infix operator definition.