# How do I use the modulus operator?

Tags: modulo, rescript

When using the `%` operator I am left with the error "Did you forget a `,` here?". Is there another keyword for `%` in ReScript?

```js
Js.log(20 % 2)
```

Note: This is a translation of [this question for ReasonML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68798893/7943564).

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator is a plain function called `mod` in ReScript. It can be used either with or without a pipe:

```js
let x = 20->mod(2)
let y = mod(20, 2)
```

It's documented in the [language overview](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/overview#number), comparing JavaScript constructs with their equivalent in ReScript.